# Excel VBA - Formula writing error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to bring a formula inside my vba code and I am getting an error inside it. Please have a look into the code and kindly share your thoughts.

This is my excel function that was written in VBA Code :

```
GetUniqueCount(Range,Value)
```

And here is the VBA Code trying to make use of it :

```
Sheets("sheet2").Activate
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").UsedRange
            lastrow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
        End With

    For i = 14 To lastrow
        check = Range("h" & i).Value
        If check <> "" Then
         Range("I" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.GetUniqueCount(sheet1!.Range("A1:B100"), check)
        Else
        Range("I" & i).Value = ""
    Next
```

The range for the function comes from a different sheet. How do I write it in VBA?

This is the function for it :

```
Function GetUniqueCount(Rng1 As Range, Lookup As String) As Long
Dim x, dict
Dim i As Long, cnt As Long
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
x = Rng1.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    If x(i, 1) = Lookup Then
        dict.Item(x(i, 1) & x(i, 2)) = ""
    End If
Next i
GetUniqueCount = dict.Count
End Function
```

Comment: yes. I defined that function inside my VBA code in a separate module. How do I call that function and How do I assign the range for it from a separate sheet?

Comment: is it "Sheet1" as sheet's name ? or `sheet1` as `CodeName` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado sheet1 as the name of the sheet

Comment: change to sheets("Sheet1").Range  as @ShaiRado suggests

Comment: @VBA_Begineer see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no worksheet function by the name of GetUniqueCount. If this is a function you have in your code then the way to call it would be like this:-

```
Range("I" & i).Value = GetUniqueCount("Sheet1".Range("A1:B100"), check)
```

This code presumes that your function is either on the same code sheet as the calling procedure or declared public. It must take two arguments, the first of which must be a range, the second of the same data type as `check`. If you didn't declare `check` (which isn't a good idea) then its data type will be Variant.

Comment: I tried to declare check as Variant. It is giving me an error - Argument mismatch

Comment: You are starting to pinpoint the source of the error. Avoid using the Variant data type - whether by default or by intent - unless you specifically want to use its particular advantages. Look at the argument list in the function and make sure that `check` is declared as the same data type.

Comment: I started using the string type then it gives compile error - Next without for.

Comment: Check if you deleted the `Next` by mistake. VBA doesn't differentiate between Next, End If and End With. Any of these might be missing.

Comment: I restarted my machine and It works now. Thanks Sir ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You have other possible errors in your code, unqualified `Range`, etc.

Since your `Function GetUniqueCount` is not Excel's built in `WorksheetFunction`, but your own **UDF**, you don't need to call it with `WorksheetFunction.GetUniqueCount` but just `GetUniqueCount`.

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim check As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

        Dim Rng As Range
        Set Rng = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B100")

        For i = 14 To LastRow
            check = .Range("H" & i).Value
            If check <> "" Then
                .Range("I" & i).Value = GetUniqueCount(Rng, check)
            Else
                .Range("I" & i).Value = ""
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It is throwing me an error as Argument mismatch . I declared check as variant and when I declare it as String. It gives an empty string.

Comment: @VBA_Begineer at what line ? what value do you have in your cells ?

Comment: inside the if loop - and pointing straight to the check that you have.

Comment: whYou haven't answered my question, what line ? is it `check = .Range("h" & i).Value` ? or `.Range("I" & i).Value = GetUniqueCount(Rng, check)` ?

Comment: .Range("I" & i).Value = GetUniqueCount(Rng, check) - This line. Also, Sir I don't think I can declare as Variant as my function has it as String ! I have added the function on the question as well. Please check that.

Comment: OK, what type is `check` ? can you share the code of `GetUniqueCount` function ? the error might be coming from variables types mismatch

Comment: I believe its a string. That's how its described in the function. For your reference, I have added it along with the question.

Comment: and `check` is defined as `String` ?

Comment: Yes Sir, It is defined as string.

Comment: @VBA_Begineer I've ran your code and it's working for me, sure you have everything in your code just like in my code above ? I'm not getting any error

Comment: It works now. I needed to restart my excel. Thanks Sir